# JS showModalDialog not working in chrome as modal

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, showmodaldialog

I am using `showModalDialog()` in my application, for user to view articles from different sources as modal popup.

It work fine with FF and IE, but in chrome it's not behaving as modal, I can still go on parent window and click on any element in it.

I wanted to make it work same as IE and FF.

I have looked at few work-around

1) set `onfocus` event on parent window, and focus child again on it.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(checkFocus, 10);
        var mywindow;
        function openModal() {
            var a = new Array;
            a[0] = 1;
            a[1] = 4;
            mywindow = window.showModalDialog(myurl,
      a, "dialogwidth: 1000; dialogheight: 700; resizable: yes;center : yes;");
        }

        function checkFocus() {
            if (mywindow != null && mywindow != undefined) {
                if (window.focus) {
                    mywindow.focus();
                }
            }
        }
      </script>
```

but this is not seems to work as expected.

2) set `onblur` event on child window, to focus itself again

this solution i have read from some online sources. i can apply this solution if only child window is customized page from on my domain only , but as my child window can be any `url` from any `domain` It is not applicable in my case.

I need to make it work , can anybody suggest me on this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome has serious bugs with its implementation. Most importantly the window Chrome displays isn’t modal (see [Chromium bug #16045](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16045)), meaning, the user is able to interact with the original window before dealing with the modal dialog.

Comment: Thanks @axel.michel for reply, i come to know about this issue of chrome . but m looking for some work-around. can you suggest work-around?

Comment: @meghana did you have a look at the discussion below the bug description? There are a few suggested solutions (e.g. this one: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16045#c28) might be helpful.

Comment: hmm... thanks again @axel.michel, i'll try it out and let you know :)