# Sharepoint-Object # has no method 'showModalDialog' in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sharepoint-2010

Consider the following code:

```
function ShowWelcomeDialog() {
    var data = {};

    var options = {
        url: "/_layouts/xxxx/xxxxxss.aspx",
        title: "xxx xxx",
        width: 700,
        height: 950,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: myDialogCallback,
        args: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    return false;
}
```

I have this code for a button click and the modal opens fine in firefox and ie. But it doesn't open in Chrome. It gives the following error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError:Object # has no method 'showModalDialog'..

Can anybody help me on this...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399127/js-showmodaldialog-not-working-in-chrome-as-modal

Comment: what is the workaround???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to utilize [SP.SOD.execute(key, functionName, args) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407807%28v=office.14%29.aspx) in order to point function `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog` to be executed from file `sp.ui.dialog.js`

Replace the line

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

with the

```
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
```